# WebXR overlay interferes with ThreeJS AR Controller

Tags: javascript, three.js, webxr

So for school I am making a webshop that allows users to view the product in AR.
With WebXR I have added an overlay to the AR session that contains a button to reposition the model.
I found out that when I press the button, the click event on the button is triggered but also the select event on the ARController is also triggered.

Is there a way to prevent the controller from triggering when I click the button?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `beforexrselect` event and call `preventDefault()` as explained here : https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr-dom-overlays-1/#onbeforexrselect

```
buttonOnOverlay.addEventListener('beforexrselect', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```